# Nested duplicate arrays in objects

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

I am trying to take an array of objects and do 2 things.

1.) Remove objects from the array that are duplicated, create a new array with the names of the items that were duplicates.

Original:

```
var duplicates = [];

var objects = [
    {
        name: 'foo',
        nums: [1,2]
    },
    {
        name: 'bar',
        nums: [3,2]
    },
    {
        name: 'baz',
        nums: [1,2]
    },
    {
        name: 'bum',
        nums: [2,3]
    },
    {
        name: 'bam',
        nums: [1,2]
    },
]
```

Desired Output:

```
duplicates = ['foo', 'baz', 'bam'];

objects = [
    {
        name: 'bar',
        nums: [3,2]
    },
    {
        name: 'bum',
        nums: [2,3]
    }
]
```

Can anyone help with this? I am using lodash in my project.

Comment: What if you have duplicates of both `[1,2]` and `[3,4]`? They all go into `duplicates`?

Comment: When you say 'duplicate', do you mean the arrays are the same object, or that the arrays have the same length and order of items, or have the same length but not order of items?

Comment: Isn't this the same question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27852356/finding-nested-duplicate-arrays-in-javascript-nested-array-uniq-in-lodash-unde

Comment: @Barmar In my particular problem, there will never be multiple duplicates. I am dealing with a array of 3 sub arrays and while it's possible that all 3 match, in most cases, only 2 of them will match

Comment: @Xotic750 It's similar but it's actually the entire solution, and the other was a component of a certain way I was trying to solve my problem. Thought it beneficial to leave both. To answer your question, the order will always be the same so there would never be a [1,2] and a [2,1] and if so I would not want them to be counted as duplicates.

Comment: I see no real difference except you now have a different data structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If order of elements in `nums` array matters:

```
_.pluck(_.flatten(_.filter(_.groupBy(objects, "nums"), function(el) {
   return (el.length !== 1)
})), "name")
```

or a bit tidier

```
var hmap = _(objects).groupBy("nums").values();
var unique = hmap.where({'length': 1}).flatten().value();
var duplicates = hmap.flatten().difference(unique).value();
```

Comment: Thanks and this is very close. However, Your solution assumes I know the value of "1" in the duplicates. In my real-world scenario, I will not know any of the values to filter by.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know underscore.js, here's how to do it with plain JS:

```
var counts = {};
var duplicates = [];
for (var i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
    var str = JSON.stringify(objects[i].nums);
    if (str in counts) {
        counts[str]++;
    } else {
        counts[str] = 1;
    }
}
objects = objects.filter(function(val) {
  if (counts[JSON.stringify(val.nums)] == 1) {
    return true;
  } else {
    duplicates.push(val.name);
    return false;
  }
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/wokegubena/1/edit?js,console)

Comment: Thanks for the response, but it does not seem to work http://jsbin.com/bekuku/1/edit?js,console

Comment: I fixed the problems. I was only saving one of the names in the duplicate.